# Solve degrees of freedom of prototile angles for a given pentagonal tiling

Tags: geometry, polygons, tiling

I am trying to find exact instances of a [pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling), but I am struggling to solve all the angles for a given type.

Taking type 8 as an example:

[image]

where:

> $a = b = c = d$
> $C = 360 - 2B$
> $E = 180 - D/2 $

After choosing a length for $a$ , and an angle for $B$ , what techniques could you use to find a closed form solution for the rest of the angles?

My understanding is that the only property we can use of the pentagon is that all internal angles sum to $540°$.

I have also tried breaking the pentagon into three triangles, using properties of isosceles triangles to find a system of equation so solve, but this was also unsuccessful.

My feeling is that the sine and/or cosine rule would be handy, but I can't see where to apply them. I feel as though I am missing something.

I know we could use an iterative approach (e.g. bisection), but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the given angle relations and $A+B+C+D+E=540$ you can easily deduce that $A+D/2=B$. For simplicity I'll let $b=c=d=e=1$.

From the relation between $B$ and $C$ you can prove that $BD$ is perpendicular to $AB$.

The isosceles triangle $\triangle BCD$ gives you that $|BD|=2\sin(B)$.

Using the sine rule in $\triangle ADE$ we find that

$$\frac{\sin(E)}{|AD|} = \frac{\sin(\angle EAD) }{1}$$
$$\frac{\sin(E)}{|AD|} = \sin(A-\angle DAB)$$
$$\frac{\sin(180-D/2)}{|AD|} = \sin(A) \cos(\angle DAB) - \cos(A) \sin(\angle DAB)$$
$$\frac{\sin(D/2)}{|AD|} = \sin(A) \frac{|AB|}{|AD|} - \cos(A) \frac{|BD|}{|AD|}$$
$$\sin(B-A) = \sin(A) |AB| - \cos(A) |BD|$$
$$\sin(B)\cos(A)-\cos(B)\sin(A) = \sin(A) - \cos(A) 2\sin(B)$$
$$\sin(B) -\cos(B) \tan(A) = \tan(A) - 2\sin(B)$$
and then solve for $\tan(A)$ in terms of $B$.

I have not verified whether this is correct, so it is quite likely to have mistakes in it.

Comment: I thought this made sense, but now I have come back to the problem and I don't see which angles of triangle _ADE_ are known.

Comment: @brian.p.h You're right, sorry. I thought E was known, but I see now that it is dependent on D rather than B or C.

Comment: Do you think an iterative approach is the way to go? I've noticed that's how you do it in your Tilings software (which I love, by the way!)

Comment: @brian.p.h I often went for a numerical approximation (i.e. iterative approach, bisection method) just because it was easiest, and I had so many tilings to go through. I know that Craig Kaplan did work out an exact formula for the standard tile types, so it is possible. In this case you can get to $\triangle ADE$ with two known sides and a relation between two of its angles. You could maybe still apply the sine rule, plugging in the angle relation you have, and maybe it simplifies to a quadratic or cubic. If that does not work, it can help to use a given value other than B (e.g. E or $a$).

Comment: @brian.p.h I have updated my answer to something that should work, barring any mistakes.